# Trouble specifying the release from apt

Tags: apt, release-management

I'm running a system based on Ubuntu Trusty. I added the source entries for Vivid (not binary)

```
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ vivid partner
```

And then ran `sudo apt-get update`.

Now, I'd like to install gnome-commander from Vivid by building it from source. I issued the command

```
apt-get source -b -t vivid gnome-commander
Reading package lists... Done
E: The value 'vivid' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources
```

Why does the command fail? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to build dependencies for that package.

`sudo apt-get build-dep gnome-commander`

`gnome commander` is not part of Ubuntu 14.04, so you can get and compile the source without specifying `vivid`. The `-t` means **target release** like `unstable`, `2.1*`, or `sid`.

`sudo apt-get source -b -t stable gnome-commander`

Comment: So when should I specify the target release?

Comment: @marmistrz it is just the release type that you want.  You don't need to specify it if you only want the stable release.  Sometimes people want other versions of the application, so they will specify what they want.